# Redirect Customers to specific page after Login in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, custom, page

How to redirect customers to a custom page when they go to any other page.

I have set Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in to the store configuration but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

It is controlled in

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php

```
if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
    try {
        $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
        $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
        if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
            $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
            $metadata->setPath('/');
            $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
        if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
            $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            // URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

By default, Magento will read the getRedirectCookie() and take out the URL before login, and then redirect back to this URL after logging in.

You can either override this  controller or get the instance of \Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect and use

> setRedirectCookie($url)

Remember store configuration "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" must be set to No, otherwise it will default goes to a dashboard

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to redirect the Customer to the account dashboard after login.**

1. Log in to Admin Panel
2. Go to **Stores > Configuration**
3. Under **Customers**, select **Customer Configuration**
4. Expand the **Login Options**
5. Set “**Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in**” to `Yes`.
6. Save configuration.
   [image]